# App force closing when turning screen off

Tags: android, android-logcat

I can't figure out why my app is forceclosing when i turn off the screen, this is the logcat
My app has scrolling text, displays widgets, gets user location, has a pager, gets the current time, gets the battery level, so the code is pretty long so for now i'll post only the logcat, maybe you can figure something out just with that
If you need some pieces of code let me know

```
04-09 02:57:56.498: D/Evolution Launcher(16574): Stopping
04-09 02:57:56.623: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(16574): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
04-09 02:57:56.639: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(16574): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
04-09 02:57:56.655: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(16574): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
04-09 02:57:56.662: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(16574): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
04-09 02:57:56.670: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(16574): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
04-09 02:57:56.670: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(16574): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
04-09 02:57:56.850: D/dalvikvm(16574): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1120K, 6% free 20548K/21696K, paused 3ms+13ms, total 140ms
04-09 02:57:56.959: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(16574): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
04-09 02:57:57.053: W/ResourceType(16574): Failure getting entry for 0x7f030004 (t=2 e=4) in package 0 (error -75)
04-09 02:57:57.053: D/AndroidRuntime(16574): Shutting down VM
04-09 02:57:57.053: W/dalvikvm(16574): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41356930)
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.doublep.evolution/com.doublep.evolution.LauncherActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030004
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3692)
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240)
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030004
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1014)
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2139)
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:853)
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574):    at com.doublep.evolution.LauncherActivity.onCreate(LauncherActivity.java:455)
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-09 02:57:57.069: E/AndroidRuntime(16574):    ... 12 more
04-09 02:57:57.116: I/Process(16574): Sending signal. PID: 16574 SIG: 9
```

I've changed the setContentView to a different layout (different file, copied content from the old one)
and it gives me a different forceclosing

```
04-09 03:34:25.514: D/dalvikvm(18864): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1259K, 6% free 20440K/21728K, paused 2ms+7ms, total 36ms
04-09 03:34:28.553: D/Evolution Launcher(18864): Stopping
04-09 03:34:28.756: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18864): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
04-09 03:34:28.772: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18864): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
04-09 03:34:28.780: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18864): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
04-09 03:34:28.780: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18864): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
04-09 03:34:28.780: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18864): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
04-09 03:34:28.787: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18864): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
04-09 03:34:28.795: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18864): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
04-09 03:34:28.795: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18864): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
04-09 03:34:28.803: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18864): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
04-09 03:34:28.803: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18864): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
04-09 03:34:28.811: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18864): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
04-09 03:34:28.819: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18864): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
04-09 03:34:28.819: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18864): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
04-09 03:34:28.826: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18864): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
04-09 03:34:28.834: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18864): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
04-09 03:34:28.834: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18864): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
04-09 03:34:28.834: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18864): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
04-09 03:34:28.834: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18864): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
04-09 03:34:28.842: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18864): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
04-09 03:34:28.842: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18864): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
04-09 03:34:28.858: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18864): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
04-09 03:34:28.858: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18864): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
04-09 03:34:29.569: D/dalvikvm(18864): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1154K, 7% free 21232K/22604K, paused 51ms, total 66ms
04-09 03:34:29.819: D/dalvikvm(18864): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 201K, 7% free 23846K/25416K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
04-09 03:34:30.170: D/dalvikvm(18864): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 6% free 26556K/28128K, paused 21ms, total 24ms
04-09 03:34:30.420: D/Evolution Launcher(18864): Loading variables
04-09 03:34:30.420: D/Evolution Launcher(18864): Restoring prefs
04-09 03:34:30.420: D/Evolution Launcher(18864): Screen density actions
04-09 03:34:30.467: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18864): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
04-09 03:34:30.475: I/Choreographer(18864): Skipped 71 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-09 03:34:30.631: E/ActivityThread(18864): Activity com.doublep.evolution.LauncherActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.doublep.evolution.LauncherActivity$4@42858a78 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
04-09 03:34:30.631: E/ActivityThread(18864): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.doublep.evolution.LauncherActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.doublep.evolution.LauncherActivity$4@42858a78 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
04-09 03:34:30.631: E/ActivityThread(18864):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:795)
04-09 03:34:30.631: E/ActivityThread(18864):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:596)
04-09 03:34:30.631: E/ActivityThread(18864):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1316)
04-09 03:34:30.631: E/ActivityThread(18864):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1296)
04-09 03:34:30.631: E/ActivityThread(18864):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1290)
04-09 03:34:30.631: E/ActivityThread(18864):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:423)
04-09 03:34:30.631: E/ActivityThread(18864):    at com.doublep.evolution.LauncherActivity.batteryLevel(LauncherActivity.java:144)
04-09 03:34:30.631: E/ActivityThread(18864):    at com.doublep.evolution.LauncherActivity.access$0(LauncherActivity.java:116)
04-09 03:34:30.631: E/ActivityThread(18864):    at com.doublep.evolution.LauncherActivity$1.run(LauncherActivity.java:985)
04-09 03:34:30.631: E/ActivityThread(18864):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-09 03:34:30.631: E/ActivityThread(18864):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-09 03:34:30.631: E/ActivityThread(18864):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-09 03:34:30.631: E/ActivityThread(18864):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-09 03:34:30.631: E/ActivityThread(18864):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 03:34:30.631: E/ActivityThread(18864):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-09 03:34:30.631: E/ActivityThread(18864):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-09 03:34:30.631: E/ActivityThread(18864):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-09 03:34:30.631: E/ActivityThread(18864):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 03:34:30.701: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18864): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
04-09 03:34:30.701: D/AndroidRuntime(18864): Shutting down VM
04-09 03:34:30.701: W/dalvikvm(18864): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41356930)
04-09 03:34:30.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18864): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 03:34:30.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18864): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 (has extras) } in com.doublep.evolution.LauncherActivity$4@42858a78
04-09 03:34:30.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18864):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:768)
04-09 03:34:30.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18864):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-09 03:34:30.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18864):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-09 03:34:30.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18864):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-09 03:34:30.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18864):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-09 03:34:30.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18864):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 03:34:30.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18864):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-09 03:34:30.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18864):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-09 03:34:30.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18864):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-09 03:34:30.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18864):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 03:34:30.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18864): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.doublep.evolution.LauncherActivity$4@42858a78
04-09 03:34:30.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18864):    at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:657)
04-09 03:34:30.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18864):    at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1339)
04-09 03:34:30.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18864):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:445)
04-09 03:34:30.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18864):    at com.doublep.evolution.LauncherActivity$4.onReceive(LauncherActivity.java:121)
04-09 03:34:30.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18864):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:758)
04-09 03:34:30.709: E/AndroidRuntime(18864):    ... 9 more
04-09 03:34:30.741: I/Process(18864): Sending signal. PID: 18864 SIG: 9
```

Where you see the log "Stopping" it's when i turn off the screen, where you see "loading variables" it's in the onCreate, so it mean this time it's restarting but crashes anyways

**UPDATE:**
My app runs in landscape mode, so my main layout is inside land-layout only, apparently the first logcat is when i have only the landscape, the second one is when i have it inside the portrait layout

**Update 2**
0x7f030004 is a layout called numpad.xml which is not used, after deleting it, the value got reassociated to settings.xml, same problem

**UPDATE 3**
I've commented out the broadcastReceiver, this is the logcat i get
http://pastebin.com/CXYA7bJe

**UPDATE 4 PARTIALLY SOLVED**
Ok, so, the first logcat was given to me when i had the layout only in landscape, transferring it to portrait solved the first logcat

The second logcat is solved by commenting out the broadcastReceiver

This is how the broadcastReceiver looks like

```
batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                context.unregisterReceiver(this);
                int rawlevel = intent.getIntExtra("level", -1);
                int scale = intent.getIntExtra("scale", -1);
                int level = -1;
                if (rawlevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
                    level = (rawlevel * 100) / scale;
                }
                if (animToBattery == true) {
                    if (animValue < level * 1.8) {
                        animValue = animValue +2;
                    }
                    else {
                        animToBattery = false;
                    }
                    ArcView.value = (float)(animValue);
                }
                else {
                    ArcView.value = (float)(level * 1.8);
                }

            }
        };
        IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);
```

Is there something wrong with it?
I'm unregistering it in onStop(), also i don't know what that `context.unregisterReceiver(this);` is doing up there but deleting it doesn't solve anything

**UPDATE 5** 
After initializing the variable

http://pastebin.com/PAuw5fmd

Comment: Are you starting any activity when screen go off? It says that it can't find a resource `Resource ID #0x7f030004` in the activity `LauncherActivity.java:455`

Comment: On 455 line i have setContentView(R.layout.launcher_main);
The launcher_main has an include inside
I'm not starting any activity (i've commented them out for debugging)

Comment: You're probably referencing a resource in your `launcher_main` layout that isn't available on the platform version the app is executed on. It could also be that you've defined the resource in a folder with a specific qualifier that prevents your runtime environment from being able to load it.

Comment: @RotaryHearti've updated my question, maybe it can help.

Comment: @MH. if i was referencing to something not available on my platform it would crash also when i have the screen on, when i have it on everything works fine

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.doublep.evolution.LauncherActivity$4@42858a78`

and `java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 (has extras) }` seem fishy. Have you actually registered a broadcast receiver if battery levels change?

Comment: @DoubleP90: Not necessarily - that all depends on what your implementation does. Anyways, it looks like the second crash is caused by your activity not unregistering correctly as `BATTERY_CHANGED` broadcast receiver. Doesn't explain the `ResourceNotFoundException` though. Could you have a look at what constant is actually associated with the value `0x7f030004` (in your project's `R.java`)?

Comment: @MH. the value is associated with a layout (not used, it was a work in progress) i've deleted it, and now it reassociated the value to settings, still same error, this time resourceNotFoundException is settings, i've deleted that and it was reassociated to main_layout, same story

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.doublep.evolution.LauncherActivity$4@42858a78`

and `java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 (has extras) }` seem fishy. Have you actually registered a broadcast receiver if battery levels change?

`Activity com.doublep.evolution.LauncherActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.doublep.evolution.LauncherActivity$4@42858a78 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?`

I'm leaning more and more towards the fact that there's a problem with the broadcastReceiver.

**First logcat**

Judging by the logcat again, I see that there's a resource not found exception - `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030004`

Check what the `R.java` file points to as `#0x7f030004` and see if the resource actually exists.

**Second logcat**

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.doublep.evolution.LauncherActivity$4@42858a78`

Check if you've registered the receiver in LauncherActivity.

**Update**

Try making `IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter` global and then initializing it `batteryLevel`. I'm assuming it was due to scope of resolution that Android doesn't recognize your Receiver.

Comment: I unregistered it now, but still i'm getting the forceclosing, this time without the errors about the broadcastReceiver, so it was helpful but still didn't solve the problem

Comment: Post the new logcat onto pastebin and link us to it, please.

Comment: Sorry i was wrong, i've updated the question, apparently the first logcat is from when i have the layout only inside land-layout, the second logcat is from when i have it in the portrait layout, that's a bit odd, i'm still having the same broadcastReceiver problems (only when i have the layout inside the portrait layout)

Comment: I've edited my answer.

I have a test in a few hours, so if the problem is still unsolved, I'll help once I get back!

Comment: Thanks for the help :)
I've updated the question, i'll try to find the broadcast receivers, thats an old app i worked on a year ago so i don't remember what i've done to it

Comment: Just saw your update2, try regenerating `R.java`, that should take care of the first logcat hopefully.

Comment: Commenting the register out doesn't solve the problem. There's a part of your app which still requests for battery stats. Please comment that part out. 

To regenerate `R.java` just delete it, Eclipse should automatically regenerate it.

Comment: I posted a partial solution in the update, now i only have to figure out what's wrong with the broadcastReceiver

Comment: I think I got the answer to your problem

Comment: Try registering the receiver else where. Like in the `onCreate`method itself

Comment: the receiver is inside a method that is called inside the onCreate, so it would change anything, also i tried and it doesn't change anything.
Also i tried unregistering it from onPause and onStop, before and after super.onStop(), still crashing

Comment: Fixed it :) the receiver was also called from a handler, by stopping the handler in onStop() and resuming it onResume fixed it, now everything works as it should, thanks for the help :D